# Images being randomly rotated when user select a photo

Tags: html, css, web-applications, mobile, html5-filesystem

I'm making a photo selector for the mobile web app I'm working on and seems like images are being "randomly" rotated. For example, when I choose to take a photo with the phone camera and the phone orientation is landscape, the image is rendered in 90 degrees for some reason. But when I take a photo and change the phone orientation to portrait, the image is properly rendered.
If I choose an existing image, some of them will be correctly rendered and some of them not.

I already tried to find a pattern on the image size (if this was just happening on horizontal or vertical images) but that doesn't seem to be the issue since all of them have the same dimension, regardless of device orientation.

I'm wondering if there's any sane way to solve this. I just don't want the images to be rotated at all.

[Here's a code snippet to test](http://jsbin.com/abuton). I'm only testing on iOS 6 for now.

Answer (score 1):

iPhone images are saved the same way no matter the orientation. If you take the picture in landscape with your home button on the right the photo is always correct. You need to read the EXIF data to determine how to rotate it.

Here is a question related to reading the EXIF data:
[Accessing JPEG EXIF rotation data in JavaScript on the client side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7584794/accessing-jpeg-exif-rotation-data-in-javascript-on-the-client-side)

This is similar to this question:
[Camera image changes orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565507/camera-image-changes-orientation)